# Ansible - loop over nested dictionaries (without lists)

Tags: ansible

I found a lot of answers to how to loop nested Ansible dictionaries but each contained lists with named items. I have a dictionary without a list:

```
xml_files:
  file1:
    key1:
      attr1: value1
      attr2: value2
    key2:
      attr1: value1
  file2:
    key1:
      attr1: value1
```

Moreover, keys `(key1, key2)`, attributes `(attr1, attr2)` and their values `(value1, value2)` are dynamic, they might be added/updated by `combine` filter with values sent from command line. Only file names `(file1, file2)` are known.

Now, I want to update values of each attribute in an element specified by fixed xpath in each file.

I tried a task with `with_dict` for each file but I dont know, how to get to attribute names and values. I also need to run task for each attribute.

```
- name: update XML values in file1
  xml:
    path: '/path/to/file1/{{ item.key }}'
    xpath: '/some/xpath'
    attribute: '{{ ??? }}'
    value: '{{ ??? }}'
  with_dict: '{{ xml_files.file1 }}'

- name: update XML values in file2
  xml:
    path: '/path/to/file2/{{ item.key }}'
    xpath: '/different/xpath'
    attribute: '{{ ??? }}'
    value: '{{ ??? }}'
  with_dict: '{{ xml_files.file2 }}'
```

I would like to keep dictionary as it is and not rebuild it to use lists if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is what you're looking for but this is how I interact over a dictionary using `with_dict`. Also you need to use `loop_control` in order to jump from one dict object to another.

```
playbook
---
- name: Manage users group 
  group: 
    name: "{{ item.key }}"
    gid: "{{ item.value.uid }}"
    state: "{{ item.value.state }}"
  with_dict: '{{ adminusers }}'
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.key }}"



Dictionary file
---
adminusers:
  a123:
    uid: 123
    realname: "Brian"
    groups: admin
    state: absent


  a456:
    uid: 456
    realname: "john"
    groups: admin
    state: present
```

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know dictionary key names (uid, state), so I cannot access them directly. I might have an empty dictionary by default and user can send extra vars dictionary which is combined to this dictionary.

Comment: Unless you create a separate parser to discover the dictionary keys, I don't think you can interact using with_dict the way you want. Ansible needs those keys to proper interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with `include_tasks` and `loop_control`. I will still look for better solution.

```
xml_files:
  file1:
    key1:
      attr1: value1
      attr2: value2
  file2:
    key1:
      attr1: value1

my_task.yml
-----------

- include_tasks: set_xml.yml file='file1' xpath='/some/xpath'
  with_dict: '{{ xml_files.file1 }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: xml_keys

- include_tasks: set_xml.yml file='file2' xpath='/different/xpath'
  with_dict: '{{ xml_files.file2 }}'
  loop_control:
    loop_var: xml_keys

set_xml.yml
-----------

- name: update XML values in {{ file }}
  xml:
    path: '/path/to/file/{{ file }}.xml'
    xpath: '{{ xpath }}'
    attribute: '{{ item.key }}'
    value: '{{ item.value }}'
  with_dict: '{{ xml_keys.value }}'
```